# Parameter self unfilled, but when I fill it it gives expected type ' ' but got 'Type[]' warning

Tags: python, oop, pycharm

```
  class Player:

   def __init__(self):
       self.godHole = GodHole
       self.pits = []
       for i in range(0, 6):
           self.pits.append(Pit())

   def return_stones(self):
       return self.godHole.return_stones(self.godHole)
      #or return self.godHole.return_stones()
      # same warning for invoking seld.godHole.increment_stones()

class GodHole:

   def __init__(self):
       self.stones = 0

   def return_stones(self):
       return self.stones

   def change_stones(self, s):
       self.stones = s

   def increment_stones(self):
       self.stones += 1
```

When using the commented line I get self unfilled warning. when I used the first one I get the  expected type ' ' but got 'Type[]' warning

What am I doing wrong? How can I fill self parameter? Can I even access instance attributes this way?

Comment: Your code contains some errors, but first you have to provide an example where you use it, its expected result, and where the error is triggered (along with the error message).

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `godHole` of class `Player`, it is just a class, and no instantiation operation is performed, you directly use the instance method `return_stones` below, and pass in the class `GodHole`, which is wrong.

There are two ways to execute instance methods:

1. call directly using the class instance
2. when a class uses an instance method, the instance is passed in as a parameter

```py
class Player:

   def __init__(self):
       self.godHole = GodHole()
       self.pits = []
       for i in range(0, 6):
           self.pits.append(Pit())

   def return_stones(self):
       return self.godHole.return_stones()
```

or

```py
class Player:

   def __init__(self):
       self.godHole = GodHole
       self.pits = []
       for i in range(0, 6):
           self.pits.append(Pit())

   # def return_stones(self):
       # return self.godHole.return_stones(self.godHole())

   def return_stones(self, obj: GodHole):
       # obj is an instance object of class GodHole
       return self.godHole.return_stones(obj)
```